# Javascript objects properties vs array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to learn javascript (coming from Delphi/pascal) and am unclear about the similarities and differences between object properties and array values.  I did try searching the archives and the web for this answer.

Consider the following code:

```
function Show(Arr) {
  var str ='';
  for (var Val in Arr) {
      str += Val + '::' + Arr[Val] + '\n';
  }   
  return str;
}
var str = '';
var A1 = ["Yellow", "Red", "Blue"];
var A2 = {"color":"red", "Size": 5, "taste":"sour"}

alert(Show(A1));
//OUTPUTS: 
//    0::Yellow
//    1::Red
//    2::Blue

A1.push("Green");
alert(Show(A1));
//OUTPUTS: 
//    0::Yellow
//    1::Red
//    2::Blue
//    3::Green

alert('Length: '+A1.length);
//OUTPUTS: 
//   Length: 4

alert(Show(A2));
//OUTPUTS:
//  color::red
//  Size::5
//  taste:sour

alert('Length: '+A2.length);
//OUTPUTS: 
//   Length: undefined

A2.push("Green");
//ERROR --> execution stops on jsfiddle.net. 
alert("OK");  //<-- never executed
alert(Show(A2));  //<-- never executed
```

I know that almost everything is an object in javascript.  I have been reading here (http://javascript.info/tutorial/objects) and here (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

I see that an array can be accessed by index, `e.g. A1[3] --> Blue`, as in other languages.  But I see also that a property can be accessed this way, `e.g. A2["Size"] --> 5`.  So at first blush, it looks like array values and property values are essentially the same.  But arrays can be extended with a .push(value) command, whereas properties can't.

It is coincidence that my Show function works for both arrays and objects?

Actually, as I have written this and researched the topic, is it just that all arrays are objects, but not all objects are array?  So then does the `for...in` loop in Show() actually work differently depending on which type of object is sent in?

Any help clarifying this would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Uh… http://w3fools.com

Comment: Maybe this post will also give you some insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: @bjb568 -- But their site is to pretty!  I saw reference to this site the other day, but read it today.  I hear them when they say that there are inaccuracies, but when I click on the alternatives, they seemed target for advanced users, and they seem harder to get info from.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @icanc -- That was a helpful link.  Thanks!

Comment: @kdtop Is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/JavaScript_Overview) really that hard to understand?

Comment: @bjb568.  That is a good site.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So at first blush, it looks like array values and property values are essentially the same.

Array entries and object properties are indeed the same thing, because JavaScript's standard arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), they're just objects with some added features. Two of those features are the special `length` property, and the `push` function, which is why you don't see those with `A2`.

Your observation about bracketed notation is particularly spot-on. In JavaScript, you can access object properties using bracketed notation and a string, like this:

```
var o = {answer: 42};
console.log(o['answer']); // 42
```

It's not well-known that this is **exactly** what you're doing when using an array "index":

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(a[1]); // b
```

The `1` we're using with `a[1]`, technically according to the specification, is coerced to a string (`a["1"]`), and then that *property name* is used to look up the property on the object.

> So then does the for...in loop in Show() actually work differently depending on which type of object is sent in?

No, `for-in` works the same with all objects. It iterates the names of the *enumerable* properties of the object. Whether you're using an array or any other object doesn't matter.

Note that not all properties are enumerable. For instance, `Array#length` isn't, nor is `Array#push` or `Object#toString` or any of the other built-in properties of objects.

But for instance, you can see that `for-in` is the same for arrays as for other objects like this:

```
var a = ['zero'];      // An array with one entry
a.answer = 42;         // We've added a property to the object that isn't an array entry
console.log(a.length); // 1, because `length` only relates to array "indexes" as
                       // defined by the specification
var key;
for (key in a) {
    console.log(key + "=" + value);
}
// Shows (in *no reliable order*):
// 0=zero
// answer=42
```

More about `for-in`:

- [*Myths and realities of `for..in`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html) *(on my blog)*
- [My answer to the question *For each in array, how to do that in JavaScript?* here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)